# Insert object from JSON into Realm with relation based on ID

Tags: android, json, realm

I want to fetch some objects from my server and receive them as JSON objects and adding them to realm using `insertOrUpdate()`.

Currently, nested / related objects are send in whole by the server and realm does its magic inserting and relating those to each other - working perfectly.

The list of `Foo` I receive from the server looks like this (`Bar` is copied for each reference):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo 1",
    "bar": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bar 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bar 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Foo 2",
    "bar": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bar 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But this means much more data to be transmitted because shared objects (e.g. `Bar` with ID `2`) are duplicated in the JSON.

Is there a way to have only the ID of the shared object in the JSON but let realm link them to the correct objects?

So only the ID of the referenced objects are stated in the JSON (and I would need to fetch those objects as well - maybe before?):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo 1",
    "bar": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Foo 2",
    "bar": [
      2
    ]
  }
]
```

Is this possible? What's the best practice to reduce traffic when many / big objects are shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible, with the proviso that you will obviously need to change the JSON produced by the API and therefore it will need to be an API over which you have control.

I think this is a fairly standard method of working and is certainly how I've achieved this. You are basically going to change your one API ('get all foos and bars') for two APIs ('get all foos' and 'get all bars'). The output for 'get all foos' is pretty much exactly as you have shown in your last codeblock, and 'get all bars' will look similar to below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bar 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bar 2"
  }
  ...
]
```

You will then need to change your Realm model to reflect the expected JSON, in particular that you have Foo and Bar RealmObject types. E.g. (Kotlin):-

```
open class Foo : RealmObject()
{
  @PrimaryKey
  var id: Int = 0

  var name: String? = null
  var bars: RealmList<Integer> = RealmList()
}

open class Bar : RealmObject()
{
  @PrimaryKey
  var id: Int = 0

  var name: String? = null
}
```

You could then add a method to the `Foo` class to retrieve the related `Bar` objects using [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.Integer:A-) API, e.g. if order is unimportant (forgive any compile errors, can't test right now):-

```
open class Foo : RealmObject()
{
  ...
  val allBars: RealmResults<Bar>
    get() = this.realm
              .where(Bar::class.java)
              .in("id", this.bars.toArray(arrayOf<Int>()))
              .findAll()
}
```

Comment: Great! I've just had the same idea this morning. This should work. But is there something provided by realm itself which would map `Foo.bars` (the list of IDs) to an list of actual `Bar`-objects? Maybe with an annotation (e.g. like `@LinkingObjects` adds backlinks, a new `@ObjectsById` would just do the query automatically)?

Comment: I've created an issue for this to be implemented in realm: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6666

Comment: I like the idea, just need to ensure primary keys are set. And I see they've responded already. Upshot seems to be that the feature doesn't already exist and they're not going to rush that out. I'll keep an eye out, although it doesn't relate exactly to what I do (as I don't need a RealmList of related objects, just one). Looks like this is the solution for now. If this is a common pattern in your code, I reckon you could template this function for reuse.

Comment: I'll accept this answer since there is no other solution now. There's a feature request which would make this workaround obsolete: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4627